# business validation error in sync time in quickbook

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm getting the following error and would appreciate some help on how to resolve this.

> ERROR(6000): A business validation error has occurred while processing your request Business Validation Error: Unexpected Internal Error. (-30003)

Comment: You're going to need to include more information (the XML/JSON you're sending, and the full XML/JSON you get back, and your code) if you expect to get help with this.